# Looping over array of HTML elements and adding to Array

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and I'm trying to copy text from all span elements with the class **"copyme"**, sort them in reverse order, and concatenate the strings together. Once I do this, I am trying to add a paragraph containing this information to the div tag with `id="copyhere"`

Here's what I have so far:

```
    var copy= document.getElementsByClassName("copyme").innerHTML;
    var arr = [];
    for (x = 0 ; x < copy ; x++){
       arr.push(x);
   }
    arr.concat().reverse();
    document.getElementById('copyhere').innerHTML = arr;
```

Nothing happens when I do this.

Any thoughts on how to proceed? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
 var copy = document.getElementsByClassName("copyme");
    var arr = [];
    for (x = 0 ; x < copy.length ; x++){
       arr.push(copy[x].innerHTML);
   }
   arr.reverse();
   document.getElementById('copyhere').innerHTML = arr.join("");
```

If you have any questions, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Simply pasting code doesn't really help people understand what's going on, perhaps a little explanation as to what you've done to fix the code? For example, innerHTML needs to happen as you inspect each item as getElementsByClassName returns an array/list of items...

Comment: @twoleggedhorse I DID append a "if you have any questions, feel free to ask :)" though.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse I agree (that I should have explained something), but I was just about to close my laptop when i saw the question and I said "one more".

Comment: Yes, I tend to do that too

Answer (score 0):

```js
var copy= document.getElementsByClassName("copyme");
    var arr = [];
console.log(copy)
    for (var i = 0 ; i < copy.length ; i++){
       arr.push(copy.item(i).innerHTML);
   }
    arr.concat().reverse();
    document.getElementById('copyhere').innerHTML = arr;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="copyme">1</div>
  <div class="copyme">2</div>
  <div class="copyme">3</div>
  <div id="copyhere"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are not concatenating the array.

Comment: Good catch! :)

toString is called implicitly, when browser is trying to render it. That leads to joining all element of the array with default(',') separator.

Comment: Yes, `toString` will be called, but it is better to use a method like `join` because it enables you to specify the delimiter, which is better IMO. Just wanted to point that out, the "." ending instead of a ":)" may have made it sound offensive :)

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree with you about the advantage of having more control on the output(especially for beginners)

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
  var copy= document.getElementsByClassName("copyme");
  var arr = [];
  for (var x = 0 ; x < copy.length ; x++) {
     arr.push(copy[x].innerHTML);
    }
  document.getElementById('copyhere').innerHTML = arr.reverse().toString();
```